# geom_text multiple fonts (or font family with IPA+Hangul+Hiragana)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to label a graph in ggplot in which the labels contain a combination of Hiragana, Hangul, and IPA Phonetic symbols. For example, I'd like one of the text labels to read "ㅈ(/tɕ/)".

Although the label appears correctly inside RStudio's editor (and also in this post), I can't seem to get both the Hangul ㅈ and IPA ɕ to appear in the same label in geom_text(). Is there a font family that supports both? Or are these editors clever enough to use multiple fonts. If the latter, how can I reproduce this behavior inside geom_text()?

Comment: Only had time for a quick glance but does https://medium.com/@hc27oclock/using-korean-in-r-plotting-4e5762092cc8#.1w50pf7wr help?

Comment: `family = "Arial Unicode MS"` works for me.

Comment: Arial Unicode worked, thank you!